# AngularJS: Add event listener after .post()

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to learn development, so sorry if I am a bit uninformed. I tried searching here for solutions.
I have to make a comment and reply app. I am using this function to add comments to my view.

```
$scope.insertComment = function(){

    var new_comment_id = $scope.comments[$scope.comments.length - 1].commentID +1;
    var input = {
        "commentID" : new_comment_id,
        "userID": user.user_id,
        "name": user.user_name,
        "avatar_url": user.avatar,
        "says": $scope.new_comment,
        "likes": 0,
        "like_status": false,
        "replies": [] 
    };
    //Pushes changes to the global comment object
    $scope.comments.push(input);
    $scope.new_comment = '';
}
```

Each comment has reply option, with following event which displays a form to add reply to the comment.

```
$(".no-url").click(function(){
    console.log('test2');
    $(this).parent().children('.reply-form').addClass('active');
});
```

My problem is that when I add a new comment, it doesn't have this event listener associated with it. How to solve this?

Comment: The first problem is that you try to use jQuery with angular when angular will be absolutely sufficient for it. If you could add DOM for the comments that would help solving the issue

Comment: Advice: remove jQuery from the project until you understand *why*.

Answer (score 1):

`$(SELECTOR)` will select only those elements which are present in the DOM.

[`Event-Delegation`](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) could be used

```js
$(PARENT_SELECTOR).on('click', '.no-url', function() {
  $(this).parent().children('.reply-form').addClass('active');
});
```

But better and recommended solution will be to use [`ng-click`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick) directive.

Comment: `<footer>
<a class="no-url">Reply</a>
<form class="reply-form" ng-submit="insertReply(comment.commentID)">
 <input type="text" placeholder="Reply to a comment..." ng-model="comments.new_reply" />
</form>
</footer>`

This is the mark-up presently where the onclick eventlistener is attached. So should I call function on $('footer")?

Comment: Or `$('.reply-form')`

Answer (score 1):

Use [directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) with [jQLite](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element)

HTML :

```
 <div comment-click> 
    //your comment html will goes here.
 </div>
```

JS:

```
app.directive("commentClick",function(){

    return {
        link : function(scope,ele,attr){

            ele.on('click',function(){

                //put here your commnet scropt

            })
        }
    }
})
```

Add this `comment-click` attribute to your ever new added DOME element on which you want to bind the click event

Comment: why not just `ng-click`?

Comment: comment section going to behave as component .finally its your choice

Comment: I'm with @Grundy this directive does the same as ng-click, it's an overkill

Answer (score 1):

Here is simplified code how to do it with just angularjs without involving jQuery

```
<div class="comment" ng-repeat="comment in comments track by $index>
  <p>{{comment.text}}</p>
  <button ng-click="comment.reply = true">reply to comment</button>
  <form ng-if="comment.reply">
    <textarea ng-model="reply"></textarea>
    <button ng-click="submitReply()">submit reply</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks. no function declaration required. most hassle-free solution. :)